# Neo4j visualisation-manipulate the graph

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, gephi

I am currently using Neo4j Python rest client and I would like to visualise the graph and be able to amend it, add new nodes relationships etc. Also I would like the changes in the neo4j database as well. Is that possible? Also can self-loops be visualised? I have read about D3.js and Neoclipse and Gephi in http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize but I am not sure which one to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can manipulate the graph in Neo4J using Cypher, in particular using a the REST API.

Any kind of tool that allows you to interface with Cypher is potentially able to do what you are asking: it is a matter to combine some Cypher queries with the GUI.

Said that, create the right visualization for what you are doing might be tricky and general approach might no satisfy your needs: while Neoclipse can let you manipulate nodes and links in Neo4J (for free) you might want to do in a particular way (for example restricting the choice of editing or the field/properties to be changed).
Linkurious offers a solution to do that as well, but it's a commercial license.

Other solutions such KeyLines, d3.js, sigmaJS let you personalize that experience: note that they will require to create the interface yourself, but the result will be much better in case of a specific product IMHO.

So value your time and requirements and go with the proper solution.

For more tools have a look at the Neo4J visualization page: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

#### About self loops:

that's a tricky bit and there is not a right way to do those - imagine a scenario with hunders of multi-selfloops.
Personally I would recommend to NOT draw them on the chart as link/edges, while representing them in some other ways: es. glyphs, notes, bubbles on the node...

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only tool that allows this today is Neoclipse, but I don't think it's updated to use the Labels and Indexing features released in 2.0.

As such, your best bet will be using the Neo4j Browser to visualize and Cypher to mutate your graph. If you want richer functionality and want a fun project to hack on, it shouldn't be super hard to build a basic visualization for Neo that allows mutating the graph. I would have a look at sigma.js: http://linkurio.us/sigma-js-1-0-next-gen-graph-drawing-lib-web/

Comment: Can I visualise self loops in Neo4j Browser?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: What about Neoeclipse?

Comment: I don't know about Neoclipse, my guess would be no.